# Remove alias details in Nhibernate logging

Tags: nhibernate

When NHibernate logs its SQL, it uses aliases for all the columns it retrieves e.g.

```
SELECT menuitems0_.menuSectionId as menuSect6_1_
```

I was just wondering if it's possible to omit the alias information to make the SQL a bit clearer e.g.

```
SELECT menuitems.menuSectionId
```

This would help a lot when I am doing a demonstration to other people, as it will be easier to show them what NHibernate is doing under the hood.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to remove aliases but you can make output look a lot nicer if you use 'FormatSql' option. Set it to true when configuring session factory

```
config.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, "...")
config.SetProperty(Environment.ShowSql, "true")
config.SetProperty(Environment.FormatSql, "true")
```

So the output would look like this:

```
SELECT
    this_.ID as ID58_0_,
    this_.Name as Name58_0_,
    ...
FROM
    MyTable this_ 
WHERE
    this_.Name = @p0;
```

Or use [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/) for demo purposes.

Comment: That's awesome Dmitry, thanks very much. I've just tried both and they make things much easier. The profiler looks really impressive actually. Probably recommend we buy a copy, looks like a good tool (and what... three mouse clicks to get it up and running ha, excellent!) Thanks.